# HHH000513: Unable to create the ReflectionOptimizer for Entity after upgrading to Hibernate 6

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-6.x

Recently upgraded from Hibernate 5 to 6 and I see the following error in debug level.

```
12:36:11.892 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.BytecodeProviderImpl - HHH000513: Unable to create the ReflectionOptimizer for [abc.def.ghi.OrderEventEntity]
org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.PrivateAccessorException: private accessor [createdTime]
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.BytecodeProviderImpl.findAccessors(BytecodeProviderImpl.java:1250) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
```

OrderEntity.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "OMS_ORDER_EVENTS")
public class OrderEventEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "oms_order_events_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "oms_order_events_seq", sequenceName = "OMS_ORDER_EVENTS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID")
    private Long orderId;

    @Column(name = "VERSION_NUMBER")
    private Integer versionNumber;

    @Column(name = "GENERATED_BY")
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private EventGenerator generatedBy;

    @Column(name = "USER_CONTACT_ID")
    private String userContactId;

    @Column(name = "EVENT_TYPE")
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private EventType eventType;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_TIME")
    private Date createdTime;
}
```

There is no trace of anything related to this over the internet whatsoever. Currently my Spring web app is not coming up and I was guessing if this could be the issue.

EDIT:

I figured there was a `ClassDefNotFoundException` from some other external library(unrelated to Hibernate) and it was not printed in the logs. This is the reason why my application was not coming up.

Answer (score 6):

```
12:36:11.892 [main] DEBUG
```

That's a *debug*-level log message. Why are you worried about it?

#### UPDATE

The other response on this thread is wildly wrong, so let me clarify the *actual situation*.

1. Does Hibernate, as claimed, use field access by default. **No, it does not.** Hibernate uses field access when the mapping annotations are placed on fields, *as required by the JPA spec*. If the mapping annotations are placed on getters, it uses property access.
2. Should Hibernate use getters and setters here, as claimed, instead of accessing fields directly. **No, it most definitely should not.** That would not comply with the JPA spec.
3. Is this a problem? Does it result in "suboptimal" performance as claimed? **No it is not, and no it does not.** The "reflection optimizer" has at most an extremely marginal impact on performance, unmeasurable in most circumstances.
4. Should one, in general, get upset and worried when Hibernate or any other library logs something at `DEBUG` level? **No one should not.** If it was actually something to be concerned about we would, at minimum, log a `WARN`. We assume that everyone has the log level set to `INFO` by default, so when we log something at `DEBUG` it's because *it's usually not worth paying attention to*.
5. Should the user, to mitigate this non-problem, scatter `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` annotations all over their entity classes? **PLEASE NO.** Don't do that. That's awful. That's not the way JPA is intended to be used.

If you do for some reason prefer property access to field access, you can place the mapping annotations on the getters. But that's not our recommendation anymore, and it's no longer common practice in the Hibernate community.

I hope that helps, and I hope it corrects the FUD in the other answer on this thread.

<sub>**For the record:** I'm the creator of Hibernate, the person who originally added the "reflection optimizer" to Hibernate, and one of the people who actually wrote the JPA spec, including the relevant part of the spec.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

**Short story**

Place `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` annotation over your entity class.

**Long story**

When Hibernate is reading data from DB it needs somehow instantiate entity object and populate it's field values, there are a couple of options to do that:

1. use reflection access
2. generate some helper class which will do that in more optimal way (yep, reflection access is still slow)

Exception you are observing

```
PrivateAccessorException: private accessor [createdTime]
```

means following: Hibernate was trying to generate helper class, but figured out the particular `createdTime` field has private access, which in turn prevents helper class generation. However the actual root cause is Hibernate was not even considering getter and setter methods (POJO "properties") present in entity class, just because by default Hibernate prefers using field access to property access (please check https://thorben-janssen.com/access-strategies-in-jpa-and-hibernate/). So, in general, you are right: such exception is not benign - it reveals you are getting suboptimal behaviour of Hibernate.