# Private accessor exception for jpa entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity that keeps giving me this exception
**org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.PrivateAccessorException: private accessor [callbackUrl]**

Java Version: 17

Spring Boot Starter Parent: 3.1.1

As you can see, I have setters and getters explicitly declared for my entity. I have also tried adding **@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)** but the issue still persists.

```
@Entity
public class EWalletEntity {


    public EWalletEntity() {
    }

   

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CheckoutMethod checkoutMethod;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ChannelCode channelCode;





    @Column
    private Boolean redirectRequired;

    @Column(name = "callback_url")
    private String callbackUrl;

    private String metadata;


    @Column
    private String customerId;

    @Column
    private String failureCode;

    @Column
    private String paymentMethodId;


    @Column
    private String lastCallback;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public CheckoutMethod getCheckoutMethod() {
        return checkoutMethod;
    }

    public void setCheckoutMethod(CheckoutMethod checkoutMethod) {
        this.checkoutMethod = checkoutMethod;
    }

    public ChannelCode getChannelCode() {
        return channelCode;
    }

    public void setChannelCode(ChannelCode channelCode) {
        this.channelCode = channelCode;
    }

    public Boolean getRedirectRequired() {
        return redirectRequired;
    }

    public void setRedirectRequired(Boolean redirectRequired) {
        this.redirectRequired = redirectRequired;
    }

    public String getCallbackUrl() {
        return callbackUrl;
    }

    public void setCallbackUrl(String callbackUrl) {
        this.callbackUrl = callbackUrl;
    }

    public String getMetadata() {
        return metadata;
    }

    public void setMetadata(String metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getFailureCode() {
        return failureCode;
    }

    public void setFailureCode(String failureCode) {
        this.failureCode = failureCode;
    }

    public String getPaymentMethodId() {
        return paymentMethodId;
    }

    public void setPaymentMethodId(String paymentMethodId) {
        this.paymentMethodId = paymentMethodId;
    }

    public String getLastCallback() {
        return lastCallback;
    }

    public void setLastCallback(String lastCallback) {
        this.lastCallback = lastCallback;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is just a DEBUG level message ? So you do not need to worry about it and can simply ignore it. If you really want to get rid of it from the log , configure the logger level for that package (e.g `org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy`) to be INFO.

For more details , please see the answer from the Hibernate creator at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76267365/339637).